# Javascript library for drawing bar charts with timeline

Tags: javascript, histogram, bar-chart, timeline, column-chart

I'd like to draw a time series as a bar chart (I suppose it's also called column chart) preserving the scale of the time line. Example:[image]

Could you recommend a javascript library providing the code with how to visualize it?
I'm well aware of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890434/javascript-library-for-drawing-graphs-over-timelines-zoomable-and-selectable) and tried some of them, but couldn't come close to the desired outcome.

The example data in javascript format:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr[0] = -100;
arr[3.5] = 10;
arr[5] = 110;
```

Comment: Have you looked at d3?

Comment: yes, but couldn't find the way. Besides, a lot of libraries have the way to draw the bar chart with labels that leaves the timeline unscaled

Comment: Highcharts is the best library

Comment: @shreya "... providing the code with how to visualize it". Could you show me how Highcharts or any other library would produce an example picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this code, you can replace `categories(in x-axis)` and `data` with your own arrays.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

</head>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">

</div>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Column chart with negative values'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
        name: 'Bar Chart',
        data: [

    { x: 0, y: -100 },
    { x: 4.9, y: 10},
    { x: 5, y: 100 }
    ]

    }]
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: look, in your example the distance between the columns -100 and 10 is the same as between 10 and 110. They MUST differ, i.e. the 1-st distance should relate to the 2nd as 3.5:1.5 (at least optically). You could change the time point from 3.5 to 4.99 to see the problem more clearly.

Comment: I have edited the code now check it

Comment: thx, this makes it happen

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series) its very configurable.
Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpztut5f/), Just changed the type to `column`

Comment: that's exactly the problem. You can put the equidistant labels on the X axis. The problem is how to put the numerical data on X axis such that the columns have the distance between them according to them